# Assigning element's id to the variable by event listener

Tags: javascript, html

i have three buttons:

```
<div id="allbuttons">
            <button id="first">first</button>
            <button id="second">second</button>
            <button id="third">third</button>
</div>
```

and i want to work with each button's id in js code if this button is pressed, like, for example, i press button with `id = "1"` and in js code I assign this id value `"1"` to the variable `newValue`, and then i can work with this number in my code.
So i did it like that

```
let newValue
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
buttons.forEach((button) => {button.addEventListener('click', function() {newValue = button.id} )}) 

console.log(newValue)
```

and it just gives me undefined, but when i just do `console.log(button.id)` in event listener, it works and logs the id, but i dont want to log it, i want to store this id value in a variable `newValue` and work with it in code, what did i do wrong?

Comment: **1** You create `newValue` and it is `undefined` **2** You assign event listeners to the buttons. **3** You log the value of `newValue` and it is still `undefined` **4** You click a button **5** The value of `newValue` changes. **Step 5 happens *after* step 3** because you live in a universe of linear time.

Comment: You have to put ```console.log(newValue)``` inside the ```addEventListener``` function

Comment: @Quentin So it means that i actually change the variable, but my log fires out before it changes?

Comment: @xto — Yes. `undefined` shows up in the log before you even click the button, doesn't it?

Comment: @Quentin oh, yes, it actually does